# Case When LIKE equivalent in R

Tags: r, if-statement, dplyr, case-when

I am wanting to do similar to a case statement in r for a variable utilizing an ifelse statement.  For example, lets say I have the following column vector 'Letter_Test' in a data frame that has:

Alpha - Test, Beta- Test, Zeta-Test, Alpha-Two, Beta-Two

I'd like to write a statement that says basically if data is like Alpha then 'Alpha', else return the column result.

In SQL that would be (CASE WHEN Letter_Test LIKE '%Alpha%' THEN Alpha else 'Letter-Test' end).

Comment: See `dplyr::case_when`: https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/dplyr/versions/0.7.3/topics/case_when

Comment: You can use the `sqldf` library and use the actual SQL command. Otherwise, I like regex (which would be my first choice). `grepl("Alpha", df$Letter_Test, fixed = TRUE)` returns a logical vector, and you can easily wrap in `ifelse()` to assign values.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Actually not sure if I got the question right but if you mean you want to test if "Alpha" is in the column Letter-Test, then this works:

```
    > df <- data.frame("Letter-Test" = c("Alpha - Test", "Beta- Test", "Zeta-Test", "Alpha-Two", "Beta-Two"),
+                  stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
> 
> ifelse(test = grepl("Alpha", df$Letter.Test), yes = "Alpha", no = df$Letter.Test)
[1] "Alpha"      "Beta- Test" "Zeta-Test"  "Alpha"      "Beta-Two"
```

Test takes TRUE and FALSE, grepl returns TRUE if the word was found inside the column Letter.Test.

Or you can put the results directly into a new column in the data frame:

```
> df$AplhaTest <- ifelse(test = grepl("Alpha", df$Letter.Test), yes = "Alpha", no = df$Letter.Test)
> df
   Letter.Test  AplhaTest
1 Alpha - Test      Alpha
2   Beta- Test Beta- Test
3    Zeta-Test  Zeta-Test
4    Alpha-Two      Alpha
5     Beta-Two   Beta-Two
```

Comment: Grepl worked great here, did exactly what I needed to do and was easy to implement.  Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

Use the case_when()
and %like% predicate.

```
case_when(
      species %like% "Alpha"        ~ "Alpha",
      TRUE                      ~  "Alpha"
    )
```

Comment: where does `%like%` come from? It's not a dplyr predicate and not base R... If you are loading a package you need to note that in your answer.

Answer (score 0):

One option:

```
new_thing <- ifelse("Alpha" %in%  df$Letter_Test, "Alpha", "Letter-Test")
```

Another option:

```
new_thing2 <- gsub(".*(Alpha).*", "\\1", df$Letter_Test)
```

Answer (score 0):

As Rahim posted:
Use the case_when() and %like% predicate.

```
case_when(
      species %like% "Alpha"    ~ "Alpha",
      TRUE                      ~  "Beta"
    )
```

And I want to add to JD Longs comment (which i am not allowed to comment on):
%like% seems to come from the DescTools package
https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/DescTools/versions/0.99.30/topics/%25like%25